# how can I do to highlight my SVG icon and link text at the same time when I hover the mouse over the blue

Tags: svg

how can I do to highlight my SVG icon and link text at the same time when I hover the mouse over the blue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPMaQ.png)

```css
.email-svg{
fill:#757575;
}


.email-svg:hover{
fill: #2196F3; 
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-information-header-flex container">
  <svg class="email-svg" width="16px" height="12px">
    <use href="./images/icons.svg/email.svg#icon-envelope"></use>
  </svg>
  <a class="contact-information-header email" href="mailto:info@devstudio.com" href="images/icons.svg/email.svg">
    info@devstudio.com
  </a>

  <a class="contact-information-header" href="tel:+48111111111">
    +48 111 111 111</a>
</div>
```

I tried to insert an icon into the tag  with the content of the link, but the icon and text highlight separately

Comment: _"I tried to insert an icon into the tag <a> with the content of the link, but the icon and text highlight separately"_ - well then I guess you did something wrong, but how do you expect us to be able to tell you what that might have been - when you don't _show us_ what exactly you tried, and only give us such a vague and ambiguous verbal description?

Comment: Having the icon highlight together with the link text, when the icon was _not_ actually part of the link, would be counter-productive here to begin with - then I might try to click on the icon, and will wonder why nothing happens, although _you_ highlighted it in a way that gave me all the reason in the world to assume that it _was_ part of the link.

Comment: Icon _into_ the link, and then `.email:hover .email-svg { ... }` should easily do the trick here, no?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, this is my first post here. And how to add it in html?

Comment: How to add _what_, exactly?

Comment: this svg into link

Comment: Make `<svg>...</svg> <a href="...">...</a>` into `<a href="..."><svg>...</svg> ...</a>` ...?

Comment: I appreciate your help, sorry for my ugly post ;)

Comment: You may try `.container : hover * {color : red; fill : red}` Instead of red use the style you like

Comment: thank you so much! appreciate your support :)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, it't easier to wrap your `<svg>` element in you `<a>` link element.

Besides you can set the icon fill to `currentColor`

```
.email-svg{
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

This way, the icon will inherit the link's `color` value.

```css
body{
  font-size:2em;
}

a{
  color:#757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
  color:red;
}

.email-svg{
  fill: currentColor;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:translateY(0.1em)
}
```

```html
<p> <a class="contact-information-header email" href="mailto:info@devstudio.com" href="images/icons.svg/email.svg">
  <svg class="email-svg" ><use href="#envelope" /></svg>
    info@devstudio.com
  </a></p>



<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 960">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 960 960" id="envelope"><path d="M172.384 871q-27.955 0-48.17-20.214Q104 830.571 104 802.616V349.384q0-27.955 20.214-48.17Q144.429 281 172.384 281h615.232q27.955 0 48.17 20.214Q856 321.429 856 349.384v453.232q0 27.955-20.214 48.17Q815.571 871 787.616 871H172.384ZM480 581.154l332.231-218.923-12.308-37.462-319.923 210-319.923-210-12.308 37.462L480 581.154Z"/>
  </symbol></svg>
```